# React-bootstrap dropdown arrow not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Please anyone tell me why my dropdown arrow is not visible. Thanks in advance.
My current state is:

```
import { Col, Row, ListGroup, Form} from 'react-bootstrap'

 {something.Available > 0 && (
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>Quantity:</Col>
                        <Col xs='auto'>
                          <Form.Control
                            as="select"
                            value={}
                            onChange={}
                          >
                            {
                              [...Array(something.Available).keys()].map((val) => (
                                <option key={val + 1} value={val + 1}>
                                  {val + 1}
                                </option>
                              ))
                            }
                          </Form.Control>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  )}
```

I'm sorry if this problem seems trivial.

Comment: How does your something.Available looks like?

Comment: It's coming from backend.

Comment: Well, without its structure it's difficult to help. Can you mock this object with some fake data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with react-bootstrap, need to add a `className="form-select"` to get the drop down arrow. But doing that there is an issue displaying the selected value. The padding is off causing the value to be pushed from view. My fix is to create a class to override the padding

```
<Form.Control
    className="form-select form-select-override"
    as="select"
    value={}
    onChange={}
>
```

then in the css file

```
.form-select-override {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.75rem 1.5rem !important;
}
```